# Audio crackles when I run VirtualBox

Tags: 20.04, sound, virtualbox, pulseaudio, hda-intel

Recently I'm having an issue for which audio crackles when I run VirtualBox in Ubuntu 20.04.
If I then execute `pulseaudio -k` it does fix it (upon restarting programs), but still this workaround is not great.
Sometimes (much rarely though) this also happens without opening VirtualBox, just by watching a video on Firefox.

I currently have the HWE kernel `5.8.0-59-generic #66~20.04.1-Ubuntu` and my audio system is the onboard analog device as following (`aplay --list-device`):

```
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC1220 Analog [ALC1220 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 1: ALC1220 Digital [ALC1220 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

And this is what reported by `lspci -v`:

```
10:00.4 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 135
    Memory at fcb00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Not sure what to do next? How could I debug/investigate this further?

Thanks!

Comment: I think I found the problem... looks like if I change the output sink from my onboard audio to HDMI, that's when crackling happens. I should close the question with an explanation...

Answer (score 0):

The issue was *also* easily triggered when changing the output (and/or input) sink in the *Sound* menu (from integrated audio to HDMI).

I managed to make it less frequent by having *pulseaudio* avoiding resampling, by amending the `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`:

```
avoid-resampling = true
```

And seems to be happening less.

On a related note, I searched around and looks like the default resampling algorithm that pulseaudio uses is low on CPU usage but is so bad that introduces crackling, so another way to sort out this issue would be to use a better resampling algorithm (as explained [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/issues/310) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmasterrace/comments/7l95yk/psa_change_default_shitty_pulseaudio_settings_for/)).

After this search, I tried instead this solution (i.e. keep resampling enabled but with a better resampler) thus changing the `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` config once more:

```
resample-method = speex-float-10 # highest float quality (from 1 to 10), a bit more CPU usage
; avoid-resampling = false # this option is disabled
```

Now it doesn't seem to happen anymore.

Ps. [this](https://swaroop-m.medium.com/beginners-guide-for-better-audio-quality-in-linux-d41de6f35a14) is a decent audio quality guide on Linux